# How to create an EntityManager object?

Tags: openjpa

I am new to Openjpa. I need to explicitly create an EntityManager object, for a persistence unit named Draco-PU. I have the following persistence xml defined. Please help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns
/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="Draco-PU" >
<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
<jta-data-source>DracoDataSource</jta-data-source>
<non-jta-data-source>DracoUnmanagedDataSource</non-jta-data-source>
<class>dk.tdc.soa.smo.draco.db.model.DslServiceEntity</class>
<class>dk.tdc.soa.smo.draco.db.model.DslServiceCatalogEntity</class>
<class>dk.tdc.soa.smo.draco.db.model.History</class>
<class>dk.tdc.soa.smo.draco.db.model.ConfigEntity</class>
<properties>
  <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARNING, Runtime=WARNING, Tool=WARNING, SQL=WARNING" />
  <!-- <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.OracleDictionary" />  -->     
  <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was new two weeks ago, so my answer is worth what it's worth but I do like that:

```
EntityManager entityManager = 
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("nameofyourpersistenceunit").createEntityManager();
```

Comment: I tried doing that but I faced the following exception : `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager
named Draco-PU: Provider named kodo.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl threw 
expected exception at create EntityManagerFactory:
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException<openjpa-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:891341 fatal general error>  `

Comment: Hum it sounds like you're using an old version of OpenJPA (kodo was the former name), try using the 2.2.0 version or the 1.2.0 if you absolutely need the 1.x versions. But I admit I know nothing about pre-2.x OpenJPA !

Comment: Well I use maven, how did you import it into your project ? What kind of IDE are you using ? Give me just a little context on how you currently use JPA because I can't really help you out of the blue :s

Comment: Even I am using maven framework for my project.Using Eclipse Indigo to work on the code.I hope you would be able to suggest on how to use a later version of JPA.

Comment: Well try to add this dependency to your code:

    `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>`